# ruby regex for php comment block

Tags: ruby, regex

I've been trying to find the regex in ruby to match a php comment block:

```
/**
 * @file
 * lorum ipsum
 * 
 * @author  ME <me@localhost>
 * @version 00:00 00-00-0000
 */
```

Could anyone help I've tried searching alot and even though some regex I found has worked in a regex tester but doesn't when I write it in my ruby file.

This is the most successful bit of regex I have found:

```
 (/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)
```

This is the output from my script

```
file is ./test/123.rb so regex is ((^\s*#\s)+(.*?))+
i = 0
found: my first ruby comment
file is ./test/abc.php so regex is (/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)
i = 0
found: * 
i = 1
found: *
```

Here is the code I have to do this:

```
 56   def self.extract_comments f
 57     if @regex[File.extname(f)]
 58       puts "file is " + f + " so regex is " + @regex[File.extname(f)]
 59       cur_rgx = Regexp.new @regex[File.extname(f)]
 60       matches = IO.read( f ).scan( cur_rgx )
 61       content = ""
 62       if ! matches.empty?
 63         # content = "== " + f + " ==\n"
 64         content += f + "\n"
 65         for i in 0...f.length
 66           content += "="
 67         end
 68         content += "\n"
 69         for i in 0...matches.length
 70           puts "i = " + i.to_s
 71           puts "found: " + matches[i][2].to_s
 72           content << matches[i][2].to_s + "\n"
 73         end
 74         content << "\n"
 75       end
 76     end
 77     content || '' # return something
 78   end
```

Comment: Is there a problem with this regex?, if yes please expatiate.

Comment: The one thing that I found interesting in your question is that the regex works in a regex tester and not in Ruby code. It would be useful to have more information about the exact problem you have and the Ruby code you're using.

Comment: Hi, I've update the post to reflect your comment

Comment: I think the problem is not the regex, but the way you're handling the matches array.
The entire comment should be the first group that's matched; have you tried inspecting `matches[0][0]`?

Comment: thanks @AlbertoMoriconi the value I was looking for was stored in [i][0] and my original regex was fine

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `/\/\*.*?\*\//m` should do.
Also that's really a c-style comment block.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is important that each line inside the comment block begins with an asterisk, you may want to try this regex:

```
/\/\*(?:[^*]+|\*+(?!\/))*\*\//
```

**EDIT:** And here's a stricter version, which will only match comments that are formatted exactly like your example:

```
/^( *)\/\*\*\n(?:\1 \*(?:[^*\n]|\*(?!\/))*\n)+\1 \*\//
```

This version will only match a comment that has `/**` and `*/` on separate lines. `/**` can be indented by an arbitrary number of *spaces* (but no other white-space characters), but the other lines must be indented by exactly one more space than the `/**` line.

**EDIT 2:** Here is another version:

```
/^([ \t]*)\/\*\*.*?\n(?:^\1 .*?\n)+^\1 \*\//
```

It allows a mixture of tabs and spaces (ew) for indentation, but still requires all lines to conform to the indentation of the `/**` one (plus a single space).